# How to use ngrx-store-freeze with nx workspace

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, nrwl

I am using nx workspaces for my application. I have put all the reducers in the libs section because they are shared between several apps. But when creating the meta-reducer I want to use ngrx-store-freeze for development.

The way that this is recommended is with this line:
`export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [storeFreeze] : [];`

But how can I know if the app is production when I do not know which environment to import because I do not know which app will be running in the nx workspace, and the ngrx reducers are pure functions so I cannot inject the environment?

Comment: "But how can I know if the app is production"
When you pass the `--prod` flag into the cli (if you're using it).

" ngrx reducers are pure functions so I cannot inject the environment?"
Yes, but the config creation is not.

What does your build command look like?

Comment: @bc1105 Yes I use the --prod command, that is how I build it for production. The command looks like this: ng build -a=myAppName --prod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function that will create the meta reducers for you. This function accepts a paremeter which indicates if it is for production mode or not.

```
export function createMetaReducers(freeze = false): MetaReducer<State>[] {
    return freeze
        ? [storeFreeze] 
        : [];
}
```

Like this your library does not care about if you are in production mode and the user of your library can decide instead.

**Update regarding your comment**

> I have created a function, but I cannot use this function in my app.module.ts, in the imports section, before I did this: 'StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),' Now I have tried using the new function StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { createMetaReducers(true) }) but get the error: "Argument of type '{ createMetaReducers(: any): any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreConfig'." How would you resolve this problem?

You already resolved your problem but I want to give an explanation on what is going on.

Typescript and modern ECMA script has some syntax sugar to shorten certain things.

Let's say you have an object where you want to assign a name:

```
const obj: any = { name: 'Tom' }
```

Now we might not hardcode the name but have it in a variable called name. Then the code looks like this:

```
const name: string = 'Tom';
const obj: any = { name: name };
```

You can see that the variable is named the same as the field in the object. If that is the case you can simply drop the `: name` part and write it like this:

```
const name: string = 'Tom';
const obj: any = { name };
```

This code snippet does the same thing as the one above.

This is called `Object Literal Property Value Shorthand` (Please somone correct me if I got that wrong) and you can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Now back to your code. `StoreModule.forRoot` expects two parameters. The second parameter is a configuration object where you can pass in the meta reducers

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers: [] })
```

So to fix this you have 2 possibilities.

What you did works fine:

```
const metaReducers = createMetaReducers();
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
```

Another way to resolve this would be following approach:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers: createMetaReducers() })
```

Comment: thanks for the tip @tom van green. I have created a function, but I cannot use this function in my app.module.ts, in the imports section, before I did this: 'StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),' Now I have tried using the new function StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { createMetaReducers(true) }) but get the error: "Argument of type '{ createMetaReducers(: any): any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreConfig<State, Action>'." How would you resolve this problem?

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding a line before the @NgModule. I create a const like so: 'const metaReducers = createMetaReducers(environment.production);' and then use this new metaReducers const to set up the StoreModule. This seems to work for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some explanation on what went wrong according to your comment.